# jQuery: Accessing second element in .on() inside function?

Tags: jquery, arguments, advanced-custom-fields

I just wrestled with a file uploader for multiple hours because the .on('change' ..) event wouldn't fire and was able to fix it by changing the code from:

`$('.acf-file-uploader input').on('change', function() {...}`

to:

`$(document).on('change', $('.acf-file-uploader input'), function() {...}`

My problem is that the function made heavy use of `this` to animate the input field and manipulate the uploaded file.

How would I refer to the element (i.e. `$('.acf-file-uploader input')` now under this new structure? Note that there are multiple upload fields to allow multiple files, which is why I have to use classes to target them.

Comment: You could still use `this`.  It should still refer to the current `.acf-file-uploader input`.

Comment: Is .acf-file-uploader the parent of all the inputs? Or are there multiple .acf-file-uploader elements?

Comment: `$(document).on('change', '.acf-file-uploader input',` is used as delegation when the elements with the class are added dynamically

Comment: I tried using `this`, but if I log it out it returns `document`, i.e. the whole DOM. There are multiple `.acf-file-uploader` elements and each one contains an `input` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This don't work?
You need to give me more code to see what is real problem. This is working for me :D

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="myform.cgi">
  <input class="acf-file-uploader" type="file" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload">
  <label for="fileupload"> Select a file to upload</label></br>

  <input class="acf-file-uploader" type="file" name="fileupload2" value="fileupload" id="fileupload">
  <label for="fileupload"> Select a file to upload 2</label></br>


  <input type="file" name="fileupload3" value="fileupload" id="fileupload">
  <label for="fileupload"> Select a file to upload 3</label></br>


  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
  <script>
  function notify() {
     console.log("change");
   }
   $( ".acf-file-uploader, :file" ).on( "change", notify);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yea that is true, but still I wonder if this code won't work?

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm also a bit mystified by the whole thing, I initially developed this functionality in a simplistic test form that just contained the uploader field and when I got everything running I copied it over to the much longer form I use in production. It didn't fire the `change` anymore, so I restructured the listener as you see above, now I just need to find a way to refer to the `input` element in question correctly.

Comment: OK :D  I do it one sample it is working for me ...I change ` $('.acf-file-uploader input') ` to `$( ".acf-file-uploader, :file" )`. If this won't work for you just give me on of the inputs code.

Comment: Works! Thank you :)

Comment: Just a note: it works better without the comma, i.e. `.acf-file-uplaoder :file`. Adding the comma makes it fire twice.